# Household Income Data Source (Canada)

Tags: data, canada

I'm interested in accessing a shapefile or tabular dataset with household income data at as granular of level as possible in Canada (subunits on the island of Montreal specifically). Is this data available at all in Canada? Or would there be a similar dataset that would speak to socioeconomic levels at fairly fine scales (e.g., town or parts of a town)?

Comment: Have you checked the census website? I know they have boundary shapefiles and attribute tables separate (I'm thinking they may be joinable). If they have income data it will likely be in one of those tables (in csv or excel).

Comment: The [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be a more suitable site to research/ask this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some socioeconomic data from this link:

https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/datasets/Index-eng.cfm?Temporal=2017&Theme=-1&VNAMEE=&GA=3&S=0

There is income data too but it is tabular. You can download census subdivisions as boundary shapefile and then join with tabular data.